# URl regex validator HTML5

Tags: regex, url

I am validating url on my form through regex.

> ^(?:http(s)?://)?[\w.-]+(?:.[\w.-]+)+[\w-._~:/?#[]@!\$&'()*+,;=.]+$

It validates all URL for example:

https://www.example.com

http://www.example.com

www.example.com

example.com

http://blog.example.com

http://www.example.com/product

http://www.example.com/products?id=1&page=2

http://www.example.com#up

http://255.255.255.255

255.255.255.255

However it also validates URL like

www.google

www.example

www.example.

www.google.

which are not accepted URL's

I am not too efficient with regex. Please help what needs to be changed

Comment: Try `^(?!www\.[^.]+$)(?:https?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w.-]+)+[\w._~:/?#[\\\]@!$&'()*+,;=.-]+$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mG9Qr5/1)).

Comment: Hi wiktor its working however it includes www.google. urls as well. Please can you help with that too... It should not include either www.google or www.google.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/mG9Qr5/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks it works!!

Comment: www.google is a valid domain name. The fact that the .google top level domain is not available on the public internet doesn't stop someone with access to their own name server from setting it up as a local domain name. I think you need to have a think about what you want to accept as a valid url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a regex in HTML5 `pattern` attribute you should escape characters very carefully, as those browsers that have ES6+ standard implemented might throw an exception when they "see" `[\w\.-]` (no need to escape dot, and once the pattern is compiled with `u` flag, it becomes an error).

Now, to fix the issue, you may add a `(?!www\.[^.]+\.?$)` lookahead after `^` to fail all inputs that start with `www.` and then have any 0 or more chars other than `.` and then an optional `.` at the end of the string.

You may use

```
^(?!www\.[^.]+\.?$)(?:https?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w.-]+)+[\w._~:/?#[\\\]@!$&'()*+,;=.-]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mG9Qr5/2). Note I escaped both `\` and `]` in your pattern, I think you meant to match both (your original regex does not match `\` with `[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]`).

Note that the HTML5 `pattern` regex is anchored by default, you need no `^` and `$` at the start/end:

```
pattern="(?!www\.[^.]+\.?$)(?:https?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w.-]+)+[\w._~:/?#[\\\]@!$&'()*+,;=.-]+"
```

But you may still keep them if you want.

Comment: I need a little help again, I have come across a situation, where example.com/ is verifying as well whereas it should not... example.com/product is correct however example.com/ is not... please help to overcome this situation as well